# how to compress audio file in iphone application

Tags: ios, audio, compression, mp3

i am developing a new application,for that app i need to compress the audio files.i dono how to do that.can any one help?

Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best choice of audio format depends on how you are using the audio; for example, is it for a short alert sound? Or is it a longer piece which plays for some time?  What sort of quality is required?

It's quite likely you will need to use AAC, which is one of the most common compressed audio formats supported by iOS.

You should find all the answers in the documentation:

- [Core Audio Introduction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Playing Audio](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQPlayback/PlayingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343-CH3-SW1)